# What is the Hindu understanding of "the image of God" or "imago dei" as discussed in the western christian doctrines?

Tags: philosophy, belief

I didn't many posts around this topic. So, if anyone know or can come up with good thoughts, please do so. One concept was Bimba-Pratibimba.

Somtimes namaskaar or pranaam is talked about bowing down to the god in you, etc. So, what is the godness of the other person we are bowing down to? Or the image of God is the human and not idol and how does that all tie into the judeo-christian understanding?